# Display a CGI popup_menu sorted by labels

Tags: perl

I want to use the `CGI` module to display a [`popup_menu`](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.43/CGI.pm#CREATING_A_POPUP_MENU)
 with the values sorted by their labels, which are supplied as a hash.

I have this code

```
print $list->popup_menu(
        -name       => 'param',
        -values     => \@data,
        -default    =>['default'],
        -labels     => \%labels,
        -size       =>10,
        -multiple   =>0,
    );
```

Currently, the output has the list of values in the order of the `@data` array. I want it displayed in alphabetical order of the names in `%labels`.

Comment: What library are you using? [CGI](http://p3rl.org/CGI)? [Tk](http://p3rl.org/Tk)?

Comment: Also, this seems wrong: `-labels => %labels`. The hash is used in list context, so it expands to a list of alternating keys and values.

Comment: Using CGI, and corrected the code

Answer (score 2):

Sort the "values" by the values from %labels:

```
-values     => [ sort { $labels{$a} cmp $labels{$b} } @data ],
```